VBA (Excel) - PhantomJS driver not working with "FindElementByXPath" -> "NoSuchElementError" (working with Chrome Driver)
Use of PhantomJS: no correct/ expected behaviour
Website with web elements
Sub Logon()


Dim obj As New PhantomJSDriver 'PHANTOMdriver
obj.Start "PhantomJS", ""


    With obj
        .Get "https://logon.comuninow.net/"
    End With
    

obj.FindElementByXPath("//input[@formcontrolname='usernameControl']").SendKeys ("0101")
obj.FindElementByXPath("//input[@formcontrolname='passwordControl']").SendKeys ("9999")

obj.FindElementById("punchKind").Click



End Sub


Error 7
NoSuchElementError
Element not found for
XPath=//input[@formcontrolname='usernameControl']
Which is odd, because it works with the ChromeDriver (same code)
Thank you
Bruno
I've changed the driver to Chrome, it works perfectly then.

The solution is we need to set a fake browser size before doing browser.get("")
 With obj
    .Window.Maximize 'This is the solution!
    .Get "https://logon.comuninow.net/"
End With

